# Slick Slider data attribute syntax

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I am just adding an attribute to slick slider and its not letting it do so, kindly guide me if there's any syntax error which is causing error. I am simply adding
cssEase: 'linear', in following data attribute

```
<div class="element-carousel slick-arrow-center" 

data-slick-options='{
                      "spaceBetween": 15, 
                      "slidesToShow": 3, 
                      "slidesToScroll": 1, 
                      "arrows": true, 
                      "infinite": true,
                      "dots": false,
                      "useTransform" : true,
                      "speed" : 9500,
                      "autoplay" : true,
                      "autoplaySpeed" : 1,   
            
                      "cssEase" : 'linear'
                       
                                
 "prevArrow": {"buttonClass": "slick-btn slick-prev", "iconClass": "fas fa-angle-left" },
                                "nextArrow": {"buttonClass": "slick-btn slick-next", "iconClass": "fas fa-angle-right" }
                            }'
```

When I am adding cssEase: 'linear', its causing an error that might be appearing due to ' of data-slick-options

Comment: `'linear'` should be `"linear"`. `'` is your attribute value delimiter. There’s also a comma missing after `"linear"`. This is just JSON syntax. Make sure it’s valid JSON.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Fixed these things but unable to achieve the result to move slider at constant speed. Other attributes working fine. Thanks for the syntax correction mate.